# Is an essentially bounded continuous function bounded?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I've just started working with $L^p$ spaces, and I've learned that a function $u:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *essentially bounded* if there exists a constant M such that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |u(x)| > M\}$ is of measure zero. We also write this as $u \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

If we assume that some $u \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is also continuous, does it imply that $u$ is bounded, not just essentially bounded?

I think it would be possible to prove this by contradiction; if we assume $u$ is unbounded on a set of measure zero, by continuity we can find a small (but of nonzero measure) region around a point with arbitrarily large $u(x)$. However, I haven't really done any measure theory so I'm not sure how to go about the details.

Comment: You **essentially** did all the work. Assume $\left\|u\right\|_\infty=M$. If there is $x_0$ such that $|u(x_0)|\geq N > M$  then there is $\delta>0$ such that $ |u(x)-u(x_0)|<(N-M)/2$ for all $|x-x_0|<\delta$. This means that $\{x:\ |u(x)|>M\}\supset \{x:\ |u(x)|> M+(N-M)/2\}\supset (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ and the latter has measure $2\delta>0$.

Comment: HAH, nice pun! Isn't this comment more appropriate as an answer though?

Comment: Also I feel like I should point out that your solution seems to be for just $\mathbb{R}$, whereas my domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I suppose it's just a small adjustment.

Comment: True. Forgot about the $n$ midway writing. One just need to read $|x-x_0|$ as the appropriate norm, and change the measure $2\delta$ by the appropriate volume of the sphere.

Comment: Small thing, but this isn't necessarily true if you aren't using Lebesgue measure. For instance, take the Dirac measure, and every continuous function is essentially bounded, though not necessarily bounded.